# Exported movie time course

Tags: animation

By default exported movie

```
Export["example.swf", movie]
```

has time course from `0` to `t` and than back from `t` to `0`.

Is it possible to change that, so that the time course would be from `0` to `t` and than reset back to `0` and start all over again?

Comment: Maybe `Export["example.swf", movie, "AnimationRepetitions" -> 0]` (or `...->1` if that fails).

Comment: @corey979 Doesn't work. Neither `1` neither `0`.

Comment: See [this discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/forward-and-backward-direction-of-animation-in-avi-export?rq=1).